# StackOverflow recursion error

Tags: for-loop, recursion, encoding, stack-overflow

I'm getting a StackOverflow error in this code:

```
public void write(OutputStream output, int code) throws IOException{
    code = (code & (1 << 12) - 1) << ((writtenToOutput) * 12);
    buffer |= code;
    writtenToOutput++;

    if(writtenToOutput >= bufUsageSymbols){
        for(int i = 0; i < bufUsageBytes; i++){
            write(output, ((int) (buffer & 255)));
            buffer >>= 8;
        }

        writtenToOutput = 0;
        buffer = 0;
    }
}
```

It says its on the line with the write(output, ((int) (buffer & 25)));
It says its on this line loads of times.
Any ideas what's going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not actually using `output` inside the method besides to call the method itself, I assume you're really trying to call `output.write(int)` and not have the method call itself;

```java
for(int i = 0; i < bufUsageBytes; i++){

    // will call the method you're already in, probably not intended
    // write(output, ((int) (buffer & 255))); 

    // will call write on the outputstream, probably what you're intending
    output.write((int) (buffer & 255));      

    buffer >>= 8;
}
```

Comment: Your right I just realized I was meant to call the write method for the output stream. The outputted file is empty though so not sure whats going on ha